# Buscar id do elemento parente do parente

Tags: jquery

#### Objetivo

Buscar o *id* do "pai do pai" de um elemento.

---

#### Cenário teste

```js
function filhoPai(filho){

  var filhoId = '#' + filho;
  var pai = $(filhoId).parent().attr('id');
  
  alert(filho + ' - ' + pai)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a id="PaiId">Pai</a>
  <div id="oDeCima">
     <a id="FilhoId"href="#" onclick="filhoPai(this.id)">Filho</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Se eu usar `.eq(2)` para puxar o parent do parent, ele não dá certo:

`var pai = $(filhoId).parent().eq(2).attr('id');`

---

#### Referência de testes

[How do I get the n-th level parent of an element in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093659/how-do-i-get-the-n-th-level-parent-of-an-element-in-jquery)

---

#### Dúvidas

- Por que usando o `.eq()` não está funcionando?
- Como poderia buscar, de forma mais simples possível, o *id* desejado?

Comment: Ajustei minha resposta, dê uma olhada se ajuda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para pegar um elemento pai de mais de um nível acima use o [.parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) do Jquery.

Porém uma tag `a` não pode englobar outra tag `a`, no seu caso precisa pegar o parent `#oDeCima` e usar a função `.prev()` pra pegar o anterior assim:

```js
function filhoPai(filho){

  filho = $(filho);
  pai = filho.parent().prev("a").attr("id"); // pode usar o  id direntamente .prev("#PaiId") no luhar do a
  
  alert(filho.attr("id") + ' - ' + pai);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a id="PaiId">Pai</a>
  
  <div id="oDeCima">
     <a id="FilhoId" href="#" onclick="filhoPai(this);">Filho</a>
  </div>
  
</li>
```

Repare que não é o 'Pai do Pai' como você está pensando.

Comment: Bruno, no exemplo estou usando o `.parents`, mas quero do "pai do pai"... ou seja, 2 níveis acima.

Comment: Voce quer pegar o id `PaiId` certo?

Comment: Exatamente. Da forma que está, pega o "oDeCima".

Comment: Realmente, não é pai do pai. Nem me atentei. Obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Você fez toda a pesquisa correta, porem o codigo que você esta usando e o `parent` e não o `parents`, outro detalhe e que você quer o **pai do pai** ou seja `id=1` porque: pai=0, pai do pai=1, ...

```js
//# Exemplo
var filho = $('#FilhoId'),
    pai_varA = filho.parent(),  // # resultado => <div id="oDeCima">
    pai_varB = filho.parents().eq(0),  // # resultado => <div id="oDeCima">
    paidopai = filho.parents().eq(1), // # resultado => <li>
    ahref = paidopai.find('a'); // # resultado => <a id="PaiId">Pai</a>

console.log('filho', filho.get(0));
console.log('pai_varA', pai_varA.get(0));
console.log('pai_varB', pai_varB.get(0));
console.log('paidopai', paidopai.get(0));
console.log('ahref', ahref.get(0));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    <a id="PaiId">Pai</a>
    <div id="oDeCima">
        <a id="FilhoId" href="#">Filho</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

[Tree Traversal](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/), [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/#eq-index)

Comment: Funcionou também. +1

Answer (score 2):

Tem algumas conceitos errados na sua pergunta:

O termo "*parent*" não significa "parente" — *parent* significa "pai".

Outra coisa é que, no seu código, não existe um elemento *pai de pai* que possua um `id`. O único elemento que é *pai de pai* de alguém (mesma coisa de avô) seria a `<li>`, que é pai da `div#oDeCima` que é pai do link `a#FilhoId`, portanto avô de `a#FilhoId`:

```
<li>                    → pai de #PaiID e #oDeCima, e avô de #FilhoId
  <a id="PaiId">Pai</a> → pai de ninguém, a não ser do nó de texto "Pai"
  <div id="oDeCima">    → pai de #FilhoId
     <a id="FilhoId" href="#" onclick="filhoPai(this)">Filho</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

> Por que usando o `.eq()` não está funcionando?

Porque o método `.eq()` retorna um elemento numa determinada posição de uma coleção baseado no seu índice. Como qualquer elemento só pode possuir apenas 1 pai direto; não existe uma *coleção de pais diretos* (pode haver uma *coleção de ancestrais* ou *coleção de pais*: pai, avô, bisavô etc.), logo o `.eq()` com valor `2` irá retornar *undefined*. Como só pode existir 1 pai direto, se você usar `.eq(0)` irá funcionar, porém é redundante buscar algo pelo índice `0` se só existe ele.

> Como poderia buscar, de forma mais simples possível, o id desejado?

Como houve uma certa confusão como mencionei acima, não deu pra saber exatamente qual `id` você está querendo buscar.

Se é o pai do link clicado que você quer buscar, você poderia usar, além do `.parent()`, o método `.closest("div")`. A diferença entre um e outro é que o `.parent()` busca o pai do elemento, seja ele quem for. Já o `.closest(seletor)` busca o ancestral mais próximo do elemento que casar com o seletor (no seu caso, uma `div`):

```js
function filhoPai(filho){

  var filhoId = '#' + filho;
  var pai = $(filhoId).closest("div").attr('id');
  
  alert(filho + ' - ' + pai)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a id="PaiId">Pai</a>
  <div id="oDeCima">
     <a id="FilhoId"href="#" onclick="filhoPai(this.id)">Filho</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Mas no seu caso, realmente o `.parent()` se torna mais simples. O `.closest(seletor)` é mais útil quando se pretende buscar um elemento em qualquer posição na ancestralidade.

Se quiser pegar o `id` do elemento `a#PaiId`, a melhor forma é como proposto na resposta do Bruno Romualdo, porque `a#PaiId` é irmão do pai do elemento clicado e está antes dele (`.pev()`). Agora, o seletor no `.prev()` não seria necessário, ou seja, em vez de `.prev("a")`, poderia ser apenas `.prev()`.

---

<sup>Quando me refiro a "ancestral", me refiro à hierarquia acendente no DOM: filho, pai, avô, bisavô, tataravô e assim por diante.</sup>

Comment: Sam, seria o "PaiId"... o "em cima" do id "oDeCima"